# SQL seleccionar una cosa de dos tablas distintas en una misma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas, tengo dos tablas, una se llama PERSONAL y la otra TAREA, y no sé si es posible mediante el operador JOIN seleccionar el campo "nombre" de la tabla PERSONAL y el campo "descripcion" de la tabla TAREA que tenga un id determinado.
La composición de las tablas seria:

PERSONAL

- Nombre
- DNI
- Edad

TAREA

- Id
- DNI_persona
- Descripción

La relación entre ambas es DNI que es la clave que se propaga de una a otra por ser una relación 1:N
Me gustaría que la consulta devolviese tuplas en plan:
nombre1, descripcion1, nombre2,descripcion2,... las que haya..
Creo que es necesario utilizar JOIN y la condicion del where sería id = a un valor, pero no se como poner SELECT de ambos campos siendo tablas disntitas

Comment: saludos creo que ya te quedo clara tu pregunta pero para que aprendas un poco mas(que te sera necesario) lee esto! esta en ingles pero por las imagenes entendera mas los inner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
SELECT P.Nombre
    ,P.DNI
    ,T.Descripcion
FROM Persona P
INNER JOIN Tarea T ON P.DNI = T.DNI_persona
WHERE T.Id = IdDeTarea
```

En [esta página](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) podrás encontrar la documentación oficial para formular *queries* y su sintaxis

Comment: Muchas gracias, el whrere iría después de la condición del ON no?

Comment: Para complementar con la peticion del OP agregaria para filtrar Where T.Id = IdDeTarea despues de la linea Inner Join

Comment: Gracias Jesús, ya complementé con tu comentario. @midlab es correcto, el where después

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jesus Rodriguez

Answer (score -1):

```
Select 
    tabla.campo, tabla2.campo 
inner join 
    tabla2 on table.campo = table2.campo 
where 
    table.campo=valor;
```

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco cómo se forma tu respuesta y terminar dando el ejemplo para su caso específico. Así aprendería a construir un join. También podrían explicar los resultados con distintos joins ¿Quiere el OP que si no hay tarea asignada aparezca la persona con la tarea en blanco (LEFT JOIN)? En fin, se trata de dar respuestas lo más completas posibles.

Comment: Lo siento, tienes razón soy nuevo y supongo que tengo mucho que aprender. Gracias por el comentario